Creating a short signal transmission in HT12E based RF communication
In HT12E we continuously transmit even when the input data pins are not changed.My problem is battery optimisation. I am transmitting only ON/OFF switch state through HT12E based RF module and Since my switch is ON for long time. It just transmits the same data until switch is off. I want to transmit ON state only for a short time (a 2 second pulse) and then don't transmit even when the switch continues to be ON.During OFF state I am not transmitting data (so no worries on OFF state). I want to transmit only for 2 seconds when switch is ON then don't transmit until next ON state is inputted.
I don't want a microcontroller. I want to use simple components to achieve it.Please help!

What's "HT12E"? Please link to a specification if it something like a communication standard, or a comprehensive datasheet if it is a concrete product.

I believe it's a series of encoder/decoder ICs from Holtek. Which in turn doesn't imply anything about the radio characteristics. Anyway, I think the 2 second pulse can be achieved with something like a multivibrator IC which toggles the RF part. It's naive to think you can do something like that on the 433MHz band without some manner of intelligent IC however, because everything that isn't narrowband FM will struggle with reliability on the open band. Some plain OOK receiver would get easily jammed.
